# How to create a new Visio file using pywin32?

Tags: python, excel, visio

I'm new to pywin32 and I'm trying to use it to create a blank Visio file. I know how to do this for an Excel spreadsheet, but I'm unsure of how to similarly create a new .vsdx file.

I know for making a new Excel sheet the code looks something like this:

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add()
workbook.SaveAs(new_file_path+'\UpdatedSheet.xls')
```

How would I edit this so it creates a new Visio document instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this :

```
visio = win32com.client.Dispatch("Visio.Application")
doc = visio.Documents.Add("Basic Diagram.vst")
doc.SaveAs(new_file_path+'/test.vsdx')
```